# Surgically extracting datum from nested JSON object using Python

Tags: python, json

From this nested JSON object I need to parse out and pretty print the value for `"id"` and the value for `"location"`.

```
    {
        "links": {
            "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs?skills=data%20science"
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 121,
                "type": "job",
                "attributes": {
                    "title": "Data Scientist",
                    "date": "2014-01-22T15:25:00.000Z",
                    "description": "Data scientists are in increasingly high demand amongst tech companies in London. Generally a combination of business acumen and technical skills are sought. Big data experience ..."
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "location": {
                        "links": {
                            "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/location"
                        },
                        "data": {
                            "type": "location",
                            "id": 3
                        }
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "links": {
                            "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/country"
                        },
                        "data": {
                            "type": "country",
                            "id": 1
                        }
                    },
```

I've been trying to grab it in this way:

```
with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


for item in data["data"]:
    for job in data['id']:
        for title in data['data']:
            print(title.get('location')
```

but I've not been able to grab the data I need.

How can I extract only those datum that I'm interested in?

### Edit

I've been trying this as some kind of exploration, but even this crashes before the file finishes:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


for item in data["data"]:
    for job in item:
            print( job )
```

Comment: yeah true- I've since changed it- kind of making some exploration. I put the new code in the op under **edit**

Comment: I copied your code and downloaded your file and got no errors.

Comment: ah-- yeah- I changed it since I wrote that. but still I can't get what I'm looking for. now it's more like this `for item in data["data"]: for attributes in item: for title in attributes['title']: print( title )` what I'm actually trying to get is a location associated with an id

Comment: But are you still getting an EOF error?

Comment: no, not anymore. now I'm just having trouble pin pointing that data

Comment: Edit your question so it's not about EOF. And if I understand which data you want, just `print(item['id'], item['relationships']['location'])`.

Comment: nice man- that worked- thank you. do you know maybe how I could sort them by location?

Comment: put something as an answer and I'll accept it- you've been really helpful- I apprecaite it

Comment: The location is a dictionary so you'd have to clarify how you want to sort it.

Comment: :/ what do you mean? I'm not so good at this- parsing using python

Comment: It's not clear how `{"links": {"self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/location"}, "data": {"type": "location", "id": 3}}` would be considered greater or less than another dictionary with a similar structure. Do you perhaps want to sort by a value inside that?

Comment: mmm, well I was thinking that the `id` for location is has multiple instances of the same- like for example `5`, so just to like- count then all up by that you know?

Comment: Do you want to print out the whole location dict, or just that ID? The other parts seem redundant.

Comment: which other parts do you mean? this is a component that's suposed to hook in with someone elses code tomorrow so I'm kind of reluctant to cut stuff out

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877220/sorting-output-of-python-file-by-location-increment-by-common-id

Comment: *grumble* -- if you've parsed it successfully, it's not a JSON object any longer, it's just a Python data structure; the fact that it was originally JSON is 100% completely irrelevant to how you then read, manipulate or search it. Why do people asking questions of this sort always reference JSON?

Comment: my bad- it's cause it was coming from json in the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm taking a leap and guessing the info you really want in the end, which is a list of item IDs for each location ID:

```
import json
from collections import defaultdict

with open('prettyPrint.txt') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)

locations = defaultdict(int)

for item in data['data']:
    location = item['relationships']['location']['data']['id']
    locations[location] += 1

print(locations)
```

Comment: is there a way to just get the counts though and not the specific ids?

Comment: @s.matthew.english I just copied the code and tested it and it works fine. Are you running a variation of my code?

Comment: yeah I was- but I just check it and now it works. man- you're pretty skillful at python