# Sorting output of Python file by location, increment by common id

Tags: python, json

There's multiple instances of data that share the same location id's, for example in the output below there are many `3`s:

```
    121 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/location'}}
    122 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/122/location'}}
    120 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/120/location'}}
    119 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/119/location'}}
    191 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/191/location'}}
    190 {'data': {'id': 52, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/190/location'}}
    193 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/193/location'}}
    187 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/187/location'}}
    189 {'data': {'id': 52, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/189/location'}}
    186 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/186/location'}}
    198 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/198/location'}}
    196 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/196/location'}}
    199 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/199/location'}}
    201 {'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'}, 'links': {'self': 'http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/201/location'}}
```

I'd like to sort these all in the style of:

```
{'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'} 15
{'data': {'id': 4, 'type': 'location'} 6
{'data': {'id': 5, 'type': 'location'} 0
{'data': {'id': 6, 'type': 'location'} 11
```

Is there a way to adapt that Python script to output the data like that?

Actually it's coming from this JSON file, that looks like so:

```
    {
        "links": {
            "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs?skills=data%20science"
        },
        "data": [
            {
                "id": 121,
                "type": "job",
                "attributes": {
                    "title": "Data Scientist",
                    "date": "2014-01-22T15:25:00.000Z",
                    "description": "Data scientists are in increasingly high demand amongst tech companies in London. Generally a combination of business acumen and technical skills are sought. Big data experience ..."
                },
                "relationships": {
                    "location": {
                        "links": {
                            "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/location"
                        },
                        "data": {
                            "type": "location",
                            "id": 3
                        }
                    },
                    "country": {
                        "links": {
                            "self": "http://localhost:2510/api/v2/jobs/121/country"
                        },
                        "data": {
                            "type": "country",
                            "id": 1
                        }
                    },
                    "skills": {
                        "links": {
```

and parsed using the following Python script:

```
import json
from pprint import pprint

with open('data.json') as data_file:
    data = json.load(data_file)


    for item in data["data"]:
        print(item['id'], item['relationships']['location'])
```

[This is the full data file in my GitHub](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/s-matthew-english/literate-octo-robot/master/extract.txt).

Comment: Python `dict`s are not ordered. Check out the `OrderedDict` from the `collections` module if you wish to use a `dict`-like container which can enforce ordering.

Comment: Yes, but the "data" dicts are in a list, which *can* be sorted. In any event, it seems OP also wants to count, unless I am misunderstanding.

Comment: Ah, the last column is counts. I guess ordered `dict`s are not needed then.

Comment: what do you think of the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40876418/surgically-extracting-datum-from-nested-json-object-using-python?noredirect=1#comment68968952_40876418)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have a list of items with a structure like this:

```
...

{{'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'} ... }
{{'data': {'id': 3, 'type': 'location'} ... }
{{'data': {'id': 4, 'type': 'location'} ... }

...
```

And you want to count the number of items with each unique combination of `id` and `type`, and print the results in sorted order?

You could use the general counting dictionary pattern:

```
counts = dict()
for item in data['data']:
    # here I assume the items you are looking for are locations
    # for it to be a key, it has to be immutable, so make it a tuple
    val = item['relationships']['location']['data']
    location_tuple = (val['id'], val['type'])
    if location_tuple in counts:
        counts[location_tuple] += 1
    else:
        counts[location_tuple] = 1

# print them out in order, first send to list of tuples and sort
results = counts.items()
results.sort() # will sort on first item, which will be id

# results come in like so: ((3, location), 15)
for item in results:
    print 'id:', item[0][0], 'type:', item[0][1], 'count:' item[1]
```

Basic idea here is that you can use the dictionary to count using tuples as keys of all the distinct things you want to count, and then use items to get it as a list of tuples, which can be sorted. Tuples are sorted by first-element, second-element, and so on, recursively, so take care when building tuples to put your first sort key in the first position, and so on, or you'll have to make adjustments to your sort call. You may have to adjust what I have depending on what you want to extract and print.

Answer (score 1):

Put data in database (SQLite for example) then "GROUP BY".